# SwiftUI - How to make a center-aligned menu?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, menu, alignment

I am trying to make a menu with SwiftUI on iOS.

**If the button that opens the menu is center-aligned, I wish the menu would be center-aligned as well. Regardless of the icon or texts used in the button. How to do it?**

What is strange is that menu's alignment changes depending on the button's content. If I use one icon, it is center-aligned as expected. But if I use another icon, it is left-aligned.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Some text.")
                }
                
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Menu {
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("Menu item", systemImage: "star")
                        }
                        
                        Button(action: {}) {
                            Label("Menu item", systemImage: "star")
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus") // left-aligned menu
                        // Image(systemName: "line.horizontal.3") // center-aligned menu
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .padding()
                            .background(Color.accentColor)
                            .clipShape(Rectangle())
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Content")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

So far I have tried few things: adding .frame, embedding menu and button in HStacks and VStacks.

The only thing that center-aligned menu with plus button was this:

```
// other code

Menu {
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Menu item", systemImage: "star")
    }
    
    Button(action: {}) {
        Label("Menu item", systemImage: "star")
    }
} label: {
    HStack {
        Spacer()
            .allowsHitTesting(false)
        
        Image(systemName: "plus")
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding()
            .background(Color.accentColor)
            .clipShape(Rectangle())
        
        Spacer()
            .allowsHitTesting(false)
    }
}

// other code
```

After I have embedded label Image in HStack with Spacer() before and after - menu is centered. But... these Spacers are now clickable which I don't want. I was thinking that adding .allowsHitTesting(false) to Spacer() will disable taps on them, but it didn't.

Any other ideas? :)

EDIT:
I have just tested with "plus" button on few other simulators and menu has different alignment on different simulators (all with **iOS 14.5**):

left-aligned:

- iPhone Xs
- iPhone 11 Pro
- iPhone 12 mini

center-aligned:

- iPhone 8
- iPhone 8 Plus
- iPhone 11
- iPhone 11 Pro Max
- iPhone 12
- iPhone 12 Pro
- iPhone 12 Pro Max
- iPhone SE 2nd generation

Is it a bug or is there some alignment option I am missing?

Comment: Hey @mallow, I just tested this and it is centre-aligned correctly, `iOS 14.4` and `iPhone SE`

Comment: On which device, did you test this?

Comment: Hey @cedricbahirwe Thanks for testing. It is centered for both icons: plus and line.horizontal.3? For me plus is not. I have tested on iPhone Xs. I will try other simulators in few minutes

Comment: @cedricbahirwe I have just tested few simulators and updated my question. Menu is left-aligned on: iPhone Xs, iPhone 11 Pro, iPhone 12 mini (which I think all have the same screen resolution). And it's center-aligned on others I've tried.

Comment: I think `SwiftUI` is trying to figure out where to put the `Menu`, we can not know at 100 where it will be positioned on each device, the best approach might be to use it as is or create your custom view with custom animation behaviours using gestures.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m thinking too. This menu is almost perfect. I think there is probably some rule to determine position based on button size. And maybe on some screens left and right margin are not equal and menu is moved to the left. If no one will find a solution for this, I will probably end up having custom menu in for this UI case.